# Ndk build linker error: incompatible target

Tags: android, c++, curl, build, android-ndk

I'm trying to build C++ library that is to be used by Android application. This C++ library uses curl library. In the linking phase following error occur:

```
     [exec] c:/Users/msavanovic/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/android-ndk-r15b/build//../toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_
64-linux-android/bin/ld.exe: error: g:/REPO/CPCAPI2/branches/b-msavanovic-x86_64_android_build-20170830/core/external/curl/curl-android/lib/libcurl.a(file.o): incompatible target
```

Both libraries are built for x86_64 architecture with target android platform 21. Curl library is built on linux and my C++ library is built on windows, but this shouldn't matter since everything worked fine when target architecture was ARM.

This is Application.mk file for my library:

```
APP_OPTIM := debug

APP_ABI := x86_64
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_PLATFORM := android-21

ifeq ($(APP_OPTIM),debug)
  APP_CFLAGS += -D_DEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -g -gdwarf-2
else
  APP_CFLAGS += -DNDEBUG
endif

ifeq ($(ENABLE_NDK_PROFILER),true)
   APP_CFLAGS += -pg
endif

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9

APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++0x
APP_CPPFLAGS += -Wno-deprecated-declarations
APP_CPPFLAGS += -Wno-write-strings

ifeq ($(NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION),4.8)
  APP_CPPFLAGS += -Wno-literal-suffix
endif

APP_LDLIBS += -llog -lGLESv2 -lOpenSLES -lz

APP_LDFLAGS += --verbose
```

This is how I built curl library:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_NDKS/android-ndk-r15b/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin

export CROSS_COMPILE="/home/milos/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android"
export CPPFLAGS="-D__ANDROID_API__=21 -I/$PRELIBS/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/$PRELIBS/lib"
export AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}-ar
export AS=${CROSS_COMPILE}-as
export LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}-ld
export RANLIB=${CROSS_COMPILE}-ranlib
export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}-gcc
export NM=${CROSS_COMPILE}-nm
export LIBS="-lssl -lcrypto"

CURLDEST=./result_libs

./configure --host=x86_64-linux-android --with-ssl --with-zlib --with-nghttp2 --enable-tls-srp --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no --with-sysroot=$ANDROID_NDKS/android-ndk-r15b/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64 --prefix=$CURLDEST
```

I checked curl libs with readelf and objdump and both of them indicate that resulting curl library has x86_64 architecture.

> readelf -h libcurl.a
>
> File: libcurl.a(libcurl_la-file.o) ELF Header:   Magic:   7f 45 4c 46
>   02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   Class:
>   ELF64   Data:                              2's complement, little
>   endian   Version:                           1 (current)   OS/ABI:
>   UNIX - System V   ABI Version:                       0   Type:
>   REL (Relocatable file)   Machine:                           Advanced
>   Micro Devices X86-64   Version:                           0x1   Entry
>   point address:               0x0   Start of program headers:
>   0 (bytes into file)   Start of section headers:          7376 (bytes
>   into file)   Flags:                             0x0   Size of this
>   header:               64 (bytes)   Size of program headers:
>   0 (bytes)   Number of program headers:         0   Size of section
>   headers:           64 (bytes)   Number of section headers:         17 
>   Section header string table index: 14
>
> objdump -a libcurl.a
>
> libcurl_la-file.o: file format elf64-x86-64 rw-r--r-- 0/0 944 Jan 1
>   01:00 1970 libcurl_la-file.o

Not sure why **incompatible target** linking error happens when I'm using same toolchain x86_64 and same android platform target 21. Any help is very welcome.

Comment: No guarantees, but maybe try using a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html)? It would help rule out any misconfigurations in your build script.